Sankey diagram with NetworkD3
I am working on a sankey diagram in R following some tutorials using networkD3 package.
I do not understand what is not working since when I run my codes, they work but in the Viewer it doesn't appear the diagram. I attach my codes and example of my data.
Thanks a lot,
CODES:
# import packages
library(readxl)
library(networkD3)


nodes <- read_excel("prova_sankey.xlsx", sheet = "nodes", col_types = c("text", "text"))
links <- read_excel("prova_sankey.xlsx", sheet = "links", col_types = c("numeric", "text", "numeric", "numeric"))


sankeyNetwork(Links=links, Nodes= nodes, Source= "source", Target="target", Value="value", NodeID="name")

DATA:
LINKS



source
target
value




10
35
1152


10
40
100


12
40
156



NODES



id
name




35
Died


40
Survived


10
Good


12
Bad




Your LINKS Sheet has 3 columns, but col_types has length 4.

thanks, it's because I have a column with ID that I did not reported in the example sheet.

You probably need to use the zero-indexed row number of each node in the nodes data frame as the index pointed to in the links data frame, e.g.
links <-
  data.frame(
    source = c(10, 10, 12),
    id = c("A", "B", "C"),
    target = c(35, 40, 40),
    value = c(1152, 100, 156)
  )

nodes <-
  data.frame(
    id = c("35", "40", "10", "12"),
    name = c("Died", "Survived", "Good", "Bad")
  )

tibble::as_tibble(links)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   source id    target value
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     10 A         35  1152
#> 2     10 B         40   100
#> 3     12 C         40   156
tibble::as_tibble(nodes)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   id    name    
#>   <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 35    Died    
#> 2 40    Survived
#> 3 10    Good    
#> 4 12    Bad

# doesn't work
# networkD3::sankeyNetwork(Links=links, Nodes= nodes, Source= "source", Target="target", Value="value", NodeID="name")



links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$id) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$id) - 1

networkD3::sankeyNetwork(Links=links, Nodes= nodes, Source= "source_id", Target="target_id", Value="value", NodeID="id")


Created on 2024-09-04 with reprex v2.1.1
